# Google Sheets - Label Value (Name) by Occurrence (1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.), ordered by Corresponding Date

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to add a Label column to count the occurrence of a particular Name by Date.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RR2SMq6OfuMCdycKSULbcEEDAI7YHNGYV2z89uDSN54/edit?usp=sharing) is a sample dataset. I have a Name and Date column and there are duplicate Names listed. I want to add a Label column that will Label the Names as "1" "2" "3" etc. - depending on which name has the earliest corresponding Date, second earliest Date, etc.

I want the Label column to look something like this:

[image: desired outcome]

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help"). There, I deleted everything from C2:C and then entered the following formula in C2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,B2:B,"<="&B2:B)))`

This formula first checks to see if any cell in A2:A is blank. If it is, then the corresponding cell in C2:C is also left blank.

Otherwise, `COUNTIFS` counts name matches (`A2:A,A2:A`) that are less than or equal to each row's date (`B2:B,"<="&B2:B`), which produces the results you're wanting.